# Sort with ignore case in an aggregation

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to sort my result with the case insensitive option. So here is my code:

```
List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();   
Sort.Order sort = ....ignoreCase();
operations.add(new SortOperation(new Sort(sort)));
```

But when I execute my query using an aggregation, it doesn't work:

```
mongoOperations.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(operations).withOptions(aggregationOptions)
```

I displayed the query in the debug console and the ignoreCase totally disappeared in the aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('persons').aggregate([   
    {  
      "$sort":{  
        "buyer.organization.name":-1
      }
    }
])
```

How can I put the ignore case option in my aggregation?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this was using [MongoDB Collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) and add it in the `mongoOperations`.
I used `strength = 1` which ignores cases.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my sorting issue

```
val res =
          mongoTemplate.aggregate(
              aggregations.withOptions(
                  new AggregationOptions(
                      false,
                      false,
                      null,
                      Collation.of("en").strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.primary()))),
              Path.class,
              CountedAggregationFolderContentDTO.class);
```